# How to secure winform application code

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created winform application and now want to secure from user by creating its serial key. I already created a web service that match serial key from my database on internet. But when serial key verified I keep some secret information in xml by encryption which is I think is not secure. Anyone can crack my application code and understand logic. So my question is that which method I use to secure my some portion of application code to secure my application being crack.

Comment: they dont need a serial number or key to "crack you code" they just need to look at it in ILDasm or similar.  A user registration key is not the same as securing the source code, thats obfuscation

Comment: I understand what u said. But I need suggestions in simple words that which method I use to restrict users to pirate my software on just increase the trial period of my winform application. The information of trial period contain in xml file placed in appdata folder, thanks.

Comment: your question does not match the title - I had to guess what the real question is.  I cant say if your secret information is secure because I dont know how you created it.  It almost has to use a hash or they can use ILDASM to look at your code and learn how to decrypt the xml and change it.  They can likely increase the trial period by just changing the system clock either the first time they run it or each time they run it if you rolled your own system.

Comment: Yes thats the threat that anyone can decrypt and understand the xml and manipulate with it. So that was my question that how can I keep safe from it. And another question arise that in winforms can we create any appdata/appcode folder as we create in webforms to secure application code from hackers or what any other way u suggest?thanks.

Comment: `can I keep safe from it` subscribe to a software licensing vendor; `secure application code from hackers` already answered: obfuscation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a serial port adapter or USB Dongle and embed your software product key in it. Then you can match your product key on application start-up with attached dongle. This is the easiest and best idea. that you can use it.

Comment: can we create any appdata/appcode folder as we create in webforms to secure application code from hackers.

Comment: @user3004110 most programs dont include the code with the compiled program. you cant hide a folder from the OS or else it wont run the app, and you cant hide the app from a user on their own computer and still have it run.  As long as they can find it, they can disassemble it; make that harder for them with obfuscation.  Dongles and such are not magical.

Comment: here we don't need to add folder like that. when project built the all source code will be compiled in debug folder. It cannot be published. Make sure how do you create setup for your project and what type of project output you are taking. Just take only primary output. Your source code will be safe and no one can see your logic. BTW,my suggestion is create a dll file for your product key algorithm and use it in your project. how you can make your logic more safer.